# insert_many or insert_one not working in a MongoDB in PyMongo

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I am trying to use the insert_one function or the insert_many function to Add a Document to my Collection in the MongoDB , I keep seeing the below error , I am trying the Dictionary approach for the same , here's my Code attached below alongwith the Error , can anyone please throw some light on the same , I am new to MongoDB with Python Driver , the DB connection works fine , so does the Collection Listing , only the insert_many function(insert_one suffices for my case, but nevertheless was trying both) fails , I have tried insert_one as well :

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import collection
from pymongo import MongoClient
import pprint
myclient = MongoClient("mongodb+srv://mongouser:mongouser@cluster0-31gzu.mongodb.net/NewDB?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
db = myclient.test_NewDB
print(db)
collection = db.test_collection
print(collection)
post = [{"Lodging": 50000,
        "AirTicket": 70000,
        "Conveyance": 30000,
        "AirportTransfer": 5000,
        "EmployeeID": 5162143}]
posts = db.posts
print(posts)
result = posts.insert_many(post)
result.inserted_ids
posts.find_one({"EmployeeID": 5161234})
```

Below is the error that I am getting on the same :

```
[root@EU-HWS-LNX242 testhwa]# /usr/src/Python-3.6.8/python insertTest_MongoDB.py
Database(MongoClient(host=['cluster0-shard-00-00-31gzu.mongodb.net:27017', 'cluster0-shard-00-01-31gzu.mongodb.net:27017', 'cluster0-shard-00-02-31gzu.mongodb.net:27017'], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True, retrywrites=True, w='majority', authsource='admin', replicaset='Cluster0-shard-0', ssl=True), 'test_NewDB')
Collection(Database(MongoClient(host=['cluster0-shard-00-00-31gzu.mongodb.net:27017', 'cluster0-shard-00-01-31gzu.mongodb.net:27017', 'cluster0-shard-00-02-31gzu.mongodb.net:27017'], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True, retrywrites=True, w='majority', authsource='admin', replicaset='Cluster0-shard-0', ssl=True), 'test_NewDB'), 'test_collection')
Collection(Database(MongoClient(host=['cluster0-shard-00-00-31gzu.mongodb.net:27017', 'cluster0-shard-00-01-31gzu.mongodb.net:27017', 'cluster0-shard-00-02-31gzu.mongodb.net:27017'], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True, retrywrites=True, w='majority', authsource='admin', replicaset='Cluster0-shard-0', ssl=True), 'test_NewDB'), 'posts')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "insertTest_MongoDB.py", line 17, in <module>
    result = posts.insert_many(post)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 758, in insert_many
    blk.execute(write_concern, session=session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/bulk.py", line 511, in execute
    return self.execute_command(generator, write_concern, session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/bulk.py", line 344, in execute_command
    with client._tmp_session(session) as s:
  File "/usr/src/Python-3.6.8/Lib/contextlib.py", line 81, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1823, in _tmp_session
    s = self._ensure_session(session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1810, in _ensure_session
    return self.__start_session(True, causal_consistency=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1763, in __start_session
    server_session = self._get_server_session()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1796, in _get_server_session
    return self._topology.get_server_session()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 490, in get_server_session
    None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 209, in _select_servers_loop
    self._error_message(selector))
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: cluster0-shard-00-00-31gzu.mongodb.net:27017: timed out,cluster0-shard-00-01-31gzu.mongodb.net:27017: timed out,cluster0-shard-00-02-31gzu.mongodb.net:27017: timed out
```

Regards,
Sriram.V

Comment: not able to connect to the server

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mehta, I got it working after replicating the same program to a Windows Box which was able to reach the mongoDB through mongo Shell.